# Add multiple tables in sql CTE query

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a query like below,

```
with c(EMP_ID,MANAGER_ID,EMP_NAME,REPORT_LEVEL) as 
(
select  e.EMP_ID
,e.MANAGER_ID
,e.EMP_NAME
, 0 REPORT_LEVEL 
from    EMPLOYEE e 
where   e.EMP_NAME like 'Raj%' 
union all
select  child.EMP_ID
,child.MANAGER_ID
,child.EMP_NAME
,parent.REPORT_LEVEL +1
from    EMPLOYEE child 
join    c parent
on child.MANAGER_ID = parent.EMP_ID            
)
select  * from    c
```

I want to join one more table(timesheet) with it , in that table there will be multiple records for a single empID . Each row represent a timesheet entry for that employee , it will have timesheet status , hours  , date .

So , i want to join timesheet table to get all timesheet status for all the employees in the hierarchy. 
I am not able to join timesheet table in this query to get the desired result .

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
   EMP_ID varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   EMP_NAME varchar2(100),
   EMP_EMAIL varchar2(100),
   MANAGER_ID varchar2(20),
);

CREATE TABLE TIMESHEET
(
   ID decimal(22,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   WK_END_DT timestamp NOT NULL,
   EMP_ID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
   STATUS varchar2(20) NOT NULL,

);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its called self joining based on Parent and Child relation on the same table.

```
with  CTE as 
        (
            select 
                e1.emp_id, 
                e1.reports_to, 
                e1.emp_name,
                [level]+1
            from Emp e1
            left outer join Emp e2 on e1.reports_to = e2.emp_id
)
Select * from CTE
```

> `Blockquote`

Comment: thanks for your reply  , with query written in my post , i am getting the hierarchy of employees but i need to integrate on more table (timesheet) with this to get hierarchy as per a field in timesheet table i.e status(pending , rejected , completed or all) .

Comment: Please send me the complete table structure and your output data. I will prepare a query for you. Please mark my answer useful :)

Comment: i have updated the post , cant even mark it useful due to reputation

Comment: I got the solution , i join the result of cte written in my query with timesheet table with condition that i wanted to fulfill...Thanks!!